# Android camera2 and color effect

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to set `CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE` for capturing. If I use `ImageReader` with `ImageFormat.JPEG` everything is fine. But if I try to use `ImageFormat.YUV_420_888`, the filter is canceled and further `CaptureRequest`s return non-filtered image. Although in `CaptureCallback` both `CaptureRequest` and `TotalCaptureResult` have requested `CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE` value.

How is it possible, that Image and CaptureResult has different parameters?

And how to fix `CONTROL_EFFECT_MODE` for `ImageFormat.YUV_420_888`?